# Emacs support for D language

Tags: emacs, d

I googled a while, unfortuantely I found that the emacs mode for d is not updated for a long time.
For experienced D programmers, which emacs mode do you use?

Comment: I am a new bie to D programming language but experienced in many other languages. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I will close this question since to my limited knowledge there's no decent Emacs's support for D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find (almost) all "EMACS as D editor" answers on [this page](http://prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?EditorSupport/EmacsEditor).

Comment: I found the emacs support was very poor, even the compiler error message can not locate the source directly :-(

Comment: I can recommend KDevelop, it has no real D integration (e.g. code completion based on already written code not analysis), but it has a simple and clean interface and a really good GDB integration (e.g hover a variable and it shows the contents). If you want an IDE with proper code completion and more useful feautures you should take a look at [Mono-D](http://mono-d.alexanderbothe.com/).

Comment: @bobzhang - If it is as you say, then it is a perfect opportunity for you to contribute back to the D+EMACS community by improving EMACS D integration! :)

Comment: I am an Emacs user, just want to find the best support for emacs

Comment: @bobzhang - fair enough - good luck with your search! :) If I am an exclusive user of an IDE, and it does not support something I need, I would do it myself, and contribute back to the project. But it is just me, not all users of opensource software feel that way, I always forget that...

Comment: @DejanLekic sure. When I found D interesting enough, I would contribute my Emacs knowledge. Something suprising me is that for some languages which has a small community like Haskell, OCaml, Emacs support is awesome. What's the most experienced D programmer's editor? Just for curiosity

Comment: Editor is pretty much individual thing. What is good for me may not be as good for someone else... Therefore, I am not going to say which editor/IDE is the best. I use MonoDevelop + Mono-D plugin for D development, or sometimes Eclipse + DDT plugin.

Answer (score 7):

I've been working with the d-mode.el mentioned by Dejan for a long time and find it adequate. If you find ways to improve it for your needs, I'd be indebted if you let me know so I can roll them back into the downloadable version with credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I collected all the variants of the Emacs D-Mode originally by William Baxter and created a Bazaar branch on Launchpad, see https://code.launchpad.net/emacs-d-mode. This is known to work on Emacs 24 as well as Emacs 23. Using a DVCS to manage this code seems far more sensible than relying on code and patches on wikis!